# Scrollview is not occupying the entire screen width for s custom tab

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im using UITabBarController with custom tabs.

Im having the following code in viewDidLoad method.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTabUIView" owner:self options:nil];
    _enclosingView.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-49, self.approveStatutoryButton.frame.size.width * 2, 30);


    _scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(_approveStatutoryButton.frame.size.width*2, 0);


    [self.view addSubview:_enclosingView];
```

There are two buttons of width 244 and height 49. So im making the scrollview and the enclosing view to fit that size.

But the problem is that,

1. scrollview is not taking up the entire screen space so the buttons are hidden a little.
2. I want this to be adaptive to all devices. will it be the correct approach or is there any third party libraries that I can make use?

Comment: did u try adding it in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad ?

Comment: Just add constraints to it after adding it as subview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTabUIView" owner:self options:nil];
CGSize * windowSize=[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].frame.size,
    _enclosingView.frame=CGRectMake(0, windowSize.height-49, windowSize, 30);
_scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(windowSize*2, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:_enclosingView];
```

Note:Window size contains the width of the whole screen use it appropiately